# QT: do something on qApp property change

Tags: c++, qt, properties, onchange, notify

I'm using the QT property system and I want to run a particular function as soon as a property is modified. I followed the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html) to set up my property and its different "slots" (READ, WRITE, NOTIFY):

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(Priority priority READ priority WRITE setPriority NOTIFY priorityChanged)
Q_ENUMS(Priority)

public:
MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
~MyClass();

enum Priority { High, Low, VeryHigh, VeryLow };

void setPriority(Priority priority)
{
    m_priority = priority;
    emit priorityChanged(priority);
}
Priority priority() const
{ return m_priority; }

signals:
void priorityChanged(Priority);

private:
Priority m_priority;
};
```

If I understood properly, I should then use the `priorityChanged()` function to achieve what I want. But if I define the function in my mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::priorityChanged() {
    //my code
}
```

I get the following error message:

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

So I tried instead to write my code in the header, like this :

```
signals:
void priorityChanged(Priority) {
    //my code
}
```

but this doesn't work neither.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to implement signals. Signals are implemented automatically by Qt in separate MOC-generated files. You only need to declare signal in the header:

```
signals:
void priorityChanged(Priority);
```

and emit signal when needed (which you already do correctly).

This documentation page may be helpful: [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Answer (score 0):

`priorityChanged()` is defined as a signal. This is not a function that can be implemented.

When you use `MyClass` in another class, this second class should define a slot to which you connect the `priorityChanged()` signal. Ex:

```
class NewClass
{
    QOBJECT
public:
    // Blah blah bla

public slots:
    void WhatToDo(Priority); 
    // ...
};
```

In the implementation of `NewClass` you can define the method `WhatToDo()`:

```
NewClass::WhatToDo(Priority P)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Then, somewhere in your code you have to instantiate both classes anc connect the signal with the slot :

```
NewClass Class;
MyClass Props;

connect(Props, SIGNAL(priorityChanged(Priority)), 
        Class, SLOT(WhatToDo(Priority)));
```

You can also make the connection within the NewClass implementation by using `this` instead of a specific class instantiation.

You also need to `emit` the `signal` from somewhere within `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! But now I realize, that property definition doesn't match the one I had set in my code as is:
`qApp->setProperty("Priority", "high")`
So I wonder if instead I couldn't directly connect this qApp property to a method, something like this:
`connect(qApp->property("Priority"), SIGNAL(/* ????? */), this, SLOT(on_priority_changed()));`.
Is that possible in some way?

Comment: @tomatoKetchup the only restriction on the `signal / slot` paradigm is that both must have the same number and type of parameters. Your `signal` is `void priorityChanged(Priority)` so you must write a `slot` of type `void f(Priority)`. Nothing prevents you from changing your `signal` to be `void priorityChanged(double,double,int)`. Now you have to connect this signal to a `slot` declared as `void f(double,double,int)`, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I made myself clear on my previous comment.
I don't want to use that Q_PROPERTY anymore, as I already created it through `qApp->setProperty` (I created a dynamic property if I'm not mistaking).
So is it possible to get a "onChanged" signal out of this dynamic property, and if yes, what should I call in the SIGNAL parameter of the following line of code?
`connect(qApp->property("Priority"), SIGNAL(/*What to call here?*/), this, SLOT(on_priority_changed()));`

Comment: Ok, everything is doable. You can create whichever `signal` you want. If the signal you want does not exist in a `class`, you can inherit another `class` from it and create the `signal`. But `qApp->property()` is a method, not an object. It does not fit into the `signal/slot` approach, which is `connect(object1, signal, object2, slot)`. You should really read the link proposed by Pavel Strakhov to understand what to do.